# Remove all newlines from inside a string

Tags: python, string, newline, substitution

I'm trying to remove all newline characters from a string. I've read up on how to do it, but it seems that I for some reason am unable to do so. Here is step by step what I am doing:

```
string1 = "Hello \n World"
string2 = string1.strip('\n')
print string2
```

And I'm still seeing the newline character in the output. I've tried with rstrip as well, but I'm still seeing the newline. Could anyone shed some light on why I'm doing this wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Naming `str` a variable is not necessarily a good idea, considering `str` is a [built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`strip` only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string. You want to use `replace`:

```
str2 = str.replace("\n", "")
re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', str) # To remove more than one space
```

Comment: In my case, it was str2 = str.replace("\r", "")

Comment: I think [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes the characters from the beginning **AND** end of a string.

Comment: VERY unsafe. Wont replace all line breaks

Comment: @Toskan What line breaks won't it remove?

Comment: Won't remove "\r" (Mac) nor "\r\n" (Windows).

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned by @john, the most robust answer is:

```
string = "a\nb\rv"
new_string = " ".join(string.splitlines())
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the only one that actually removes natural line breaks. ie; from user input, not only `\n`

Comment: I want to do this for all elements in a pandas dataframe

Comment: This answer is also the simplest to read.  This one adds the least complexity to the code.

Answer (score 7):

Answering late since I recently had the same question when reading text from file; tried several options such as:

```
with open('verdict.txt') as f:
```

First option below produces a list called `alist`, with `'\n'` stripped, then joins back into full text (optional if you wish to have only one text):

```
alist = f.read().splitlines()
jalist = " ".join(alist)
```

Second option below is much easier and simple produces string of text called `atext` replacing `'\n'` with space;

```
atext = f.read().replace('\n',' ')
```

It works; I have done it.  This is clean, easier, and efficient.

Answer (score 4):

`strip()` returns the string after removing leading and trailing whitespace. see [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

In your case, you may want to try [replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
string2 = string1.replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can try this:

```
string1 = 'Hello \n World'
tmp = string1.split()
string2 = ' '.join(tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in many cases -

```
text = ' '.join([line.strip() for line in text.strip().splitlines() if line.strip()])
text = re.sub('[\r\n]+', ' ', text)
```

Answer (score -1):

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns the string with leading and trailing whitespaces(by default) removed.

So it would turn `"  Hello World   "` to `"Hello World"`, but it won't remove the \n character as it is present in between the string.

Try [replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

```
str = "Hello \n World"
str2 = str.replace('\n', '')
print str2
```

Answer (score -1):

If the file includes a line break in the middle of the text neither `strip()` nor `rstrip()` will not solve the problem,

> strip family are used to trim from the began and the end of the string

`replace()` is the way to solve your problem

```
>>> my_name = "Landon\nWO"
>>> print my_name
   Landon
   WO

>>> my_name = my_name.replace('\n','')
>>> print my_name
LandonWO
```