# How to write only a single line to file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write some content to the file. The problem is that the large contents get split over multiple lines which I don't want to do. Here is the code:-

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
SITE.max_pages=1
SITE.page_size=1

questions = SITE.fetch('questions', min=20, tagged='python', sort='votes')

with open('python_qna.txt', 'w') as file:
    for quest in questions['items']:
        if 'title' not in quest or quest['is_answered'] == False:
            continue
        title = quest['title']
        question_id = quest['question_id']
        top_answer = SITE.fetch('questions/' + str(question_id) + '/answers', order = 'desc', sort='votes', filter='!-.7zMlMaANYq')
        file.write('- - ' + title + '\n')
        file.write('  - ' + top_answer['items'][0]['body'])
```

The Sample output of the above code is:-

```
- - What does the "yield" keyword do?
  - <p>To understand what <code>yield</code> does, you must understand what <em>generators</em> are. And before generators come <em>iterables</em>.</p>

<h2>Iterables</h2>
:
:
After all the lines
End of the answer line!
```

What should be done so that the file has a single line of question and then a single line of answer structure?

The final structure of the file should be like:-

```
- - Question 1
  - Answer 1
- - Question 2
  - Answer 2
- - Question 3
  - Answer 3
.
.
.
- - Question n
  - Answer n
```

Comment: Try replacing your question's body `\n`s before writing it in the file.

Comment: There is no "\n" anywhere.

Comment: There are *lots* of `\n` in the `top_answer['items'][0]['body']`.

Comment: I found the answer here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298907/remove-all-newlines-from-inside-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string.splitlines() method did work for me:-

```
top_answer = " ".join(top_answer.splitlines())
```