# How to get rid of the 'new lines' symbols in the output at Python when retrieving emails?

Tags: python, newline

How do we get rid of the 'new lines' symbols '(\r\n)' when using Python to retrieve emails? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjd8T.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298907/remove-all-newlines-from-inside-a-string/13299031

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
s = "ABCD\n\r"

s = s.replace("\n", "")
s = s.replace("\r", "")

print(s)
```

Gives the output:

```
ABCD
```

Use `replace` instead of `strip` since it does not care about the placement of the speciefied character.